# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, xcode8.2

I am using `Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002)` to build & run my iOS application, when I am running my application on Simulator it's working great, but the same application is failed to run on physical devices & giving following error:

[image]

I have seen my device UDID in present in the provisioning profile. I am using `Automatically manage signing` option

[image]

I've followed the steps in various suggested solutions on stack overflow, including deleting all existing certificates and starting again but no luck works.

Comment: In Xcode  Preference in Account have you checked your Provisioing. Delete this and create new one. And also check In your device any other app you are using or not same bundle identifier.

Comment: @Lalitkumar I have checked Provisioning it's exists. deleted & downloaded provisioning but no luck. I don't have other applications with same bundle id on my device.